# Referring to types in *.d.ts files

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript, and I'm building a small sample app using node.js and ws. I've downloaded definition files for both. The file for node.js seems to work fine. I don't know how to use types from the ws.d.ts file.

The ws.d.ts file is from Definitely Typed: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/ws/ws.d.ts

The important parts of my script are:

```
/// <reference path="typings/node/node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/ws/ws.d.ts" />

(function(){
    const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

    // does things here

}());
```

The script works fine, but I cannot add type information. I've tried:

`const WebSocketServer: ws.WebSocket.Server = require('ws').Server;`

`const WebSocketServer: WebSocket.Server = require('ws').Server;`

`const WebSocketServer: Server = require('ws').Server;`

...but the compiler always complains that it cannot find the name "ws/WebSocket/Server" - whichever was the first part of the name.

How do I refer to types defined in a d.ts file?

Answer (score 1):

You simply write like this:

```
import * as websockets from 'ws';
```

and then later:

```
let wsServer = new websockets.Server({ port: 1234 });
wsServer.on('connection', (client) => 
{
 ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working eventually, you need to do:

```
import ws = require('ws');
```

in your code, and run tsc.exe with the `--module commonjs` flag. If you're using Sublime Text and want this to work with their Typescript plugin, you have to put a tsconfig.json in your directory:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs"
    }
}
```

...and the install Arctic Typescript plugin through Package Control, because the default one just doesn't play ball.